# How to iterate over block of text

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am writing a method inside `MimeTypes` class that iterates over contents and creates a `Hash` of extension as key and mime type as value. Here is my rspec snippet.

```
  let(:mime_content) do
    <<-FILE_CONTENT

# Mime type    extension
image/png     png

image/jpeg    jpeg jpg jpe
    FILE_CONTENT
  end
  let(:mime_types) { WebServer::MimeTypes.new(mime_content) }
```

I am not sure how to iterate over block of text. I am not sure what `<<-FILE_CONTENT` does. I am assuming it is creating a block of text and assigning it to `mime_content`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use let() like this:

```
let(:var_name) { "some string" }
```

That is equivalent to:

```
let(:var_name) do
  "some string"
end
```

Ruby also has a Perl feature called Heredoc, which allows you to do stuff like this:

```
text = <<END_OF_STRING
hello world
goodbye mars
help
get lost
END_OF_STRING
```

text will then contain the string:

```
"hello world\ngoodbye mars\nhelp\nget lost\n"
```

Heredoc sytnax allows you to do some tricky things, like:

```
puts(<<END_OF_TEXT)
hello world
goodbye mars
END_OF_TEXT
```

No one really knows all the tricky places you can insert `<<SOME_UNIQUE_ID` into code, and so Heredocs can be quite confusing.

In your example, apparently the Heredoc syntax is being used to create a multi line string inside a block.  Normally, the matching ending terminator has to be on a line by itself AND not indented.  The preceding dash, `<<-FILE_CONTENT`, means the matching terminator WILL be indented.

You can also put single quotes around the identifier, to create a single quoted string:

```
<<'FILE_CONTENT'
```

Personally, I would write the example like this:

```
text =<<'FILE_CONTENT'
blah
blah
blah
FILE_CONTENT

let(:mime_content) { text }
```

> I am not sure how to iterate over block of text.

How do you want to iterate over the block of text?  By character? By word? By sentence? By line? By paragraph?  See the String class for the various methods.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I wanted to iterate line by line. I figured it out `.lines.map(&:chomp).each` does the job.

Comment: @Kumari Sweta, If you like horribly inefficient code, go with that.  Otherwise, try `mime_type.each_line do |line| line.chomp!  #do stuff here
end`  Your way traverses the the text 3 times AND creates a duplicate of the whoe text in memory.  My way goes through the text once, and does not create a duplicate of the whole text.